# How to update curl certificate fingerprint?

Tags: ssl, curl, sftp

Recently my coworkers installed new OS on sftp server and I have bunch of scripts that use curl to access this sftp.
The problem is that I'm getting CURLE_PEER_FAILED_VERIFICATION (51).
I believe it is because my local fingerprint/certificate does not match the one on sftp anymore.
For sftp client I fixed this simply by removing line in known_hosts file, but it didn't work for curl.

PS. Searching google didn't give me any meaningful information, so maybe I'm wrong and curl does not store any certificates?

Comment: How do you run curl? What are the parameters that you are passing to it? As far as I understand from documentation you have to pass it parameters if you use it from command line or as a library.